# Data not refreshing after adding entry to database React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a page where i add products to a product list. After a successful add, the app needs to go back to the list to see the products again with the new entry added. The redirecting to the product list works fine, and i see the products again, but the new product is not on the list. In order to view the new added products, i have to hard reload the page. For some reason the component is not getting re-rendered thus not requesting the new product list from the server.

Why is this happening? How can I make the ProductPage re-render  without forcing a full app refresh.

I have reproduced the problem in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-refresh-problem-lgq12?file=/src/App.tsx).

Comment: This is caused by how you have set up your subroutes. The data for the product list is loaded by `ProductPage`. `ProductPage` includes 2 subroutes `ProductList` and `AddProduct`. Swapping between these two subroutes does not cause the parent (`ProductPage`) to remount. This means that the `useEffect` will not rerun, and the data will not be updated. To see it work without a full refresh you could add another link to the top of your page to your `AnotherPage`, After adding a product navigate to `AnotherPage` then back to `ProductPage` the component will remount and get new data.

Comment: Thank you, what i did was move the axios call inside `ProductList` now it works as expected. I was hoping to use the `ProductList` component to list different items on a different page and thus just pass the data that i wanted to render. I guess i will have duplicate components doing the same thing with two different axios calls for the two data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was pretty much covered by Jacob Smith in his above comment. However, to expand a little upon his explanation, you have a setup that looks something like this:

```
// App.jsx

return (
  <>
    <h1>Some header</h1>
    <Switch>
      <Route path='productlist' component={ProductList} />
    </Switch>
  </>
)
```

```
// ProductList.jsx

const [state, setState] = usetState();

useEffect(() => {
  loadSomeData().then(data => {
    setState(data);
  })
}, []);

return (
  <>
    <Switch>
      <Route path='productlist' render={() => <ProductPage data={state} />} />
      <Route path='productlist/add' component={AddProduct} />
    </Switch>
  </>
)
```

Due to this data flow, new data is only loaded when `ProductList` mounts, unmounts, and mounts again. However, nothing you do in either `ProductPage` or `AddProduct` ever unmounts `ProductList`, since both are rendered in that component.

This can be fixed in two main ways, move the render of `AddProduct` to the top level in `App.jsx` or, if `Axios.post` returns the new data, you can hand down the state setting method to `AddProduct` and set the state in the `.then` callback, since the parent component is not unmounted.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is that you should really hard reload after the submitting the form by adding the following code at the end of the form submit handler function of your form.

```
      window.location = '/productList';
```